# What is the correct way to fire COM events from C# to C++

Tags: c#, c++, com, com-interop, atl

We have a project with a lot of legacy code in C++ (using ATL), VB6 and more recently C#.

We have recently ported a component from C++ to C#, which fires events which are handled by components in C++, VB6 and C#.
In theory it is all working, but firing events is generating a lot of System.NotImplementedExceptions.

I have modified the code which fires the events, so that it calls each event handler individually, so that an exception from one object does not prevent it from calling the event handler in the next object.

```
if ( GeneratedChannelChange != null )
{
  // Invoke each handler separately, so that an exception in one invokation does not prevent us calling the next one.
  foreach ( GeneratedChannelChangeEventHandler del in GeneratedChannelChange.GetInvocationList() )
  {
    try
    {
      del.Invoke ( GenChan, ChangeMask ) ;
    }
    catch  ( Exception ) {}
  }
}
```

In fact, the original C++ code generated by the ATL wizard, also ignored errors returned by the invoke function.

This seems to be working correctly, but I am not happy with the high number of exceptions it generates. This is also killing the performance when running in the debugger.

I think that the exceptions are only thrown when events are handled in a C++ class. This is implemented using the ATL class IDispEventSimpleImpl. What I have found out is, that **IDispEventSimpleImpl** does not implement the function **GetIDsOfNames**. This function is definitely being called and it returns E_NOTIMPL.

Could it be, that the new C# code is calling the function GetIDsOfNames, but the old C++ code did not?

If that is the case, is there any simple way to implement the function GetIDsOfNames in the classes which use IDispEventSimpleImpl?

If my analysis is wrong, is there a 'correct' way to implement the event logic in C# (as event-source) and C++ (as event-sink)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I have fixed the problem, by replacing **IDispEventSimpleImpl** with **IDispEventImpl**.

This is more or less a drop-in replacement, but it does require a reference to the type library.

The ATL class inherits multiple base classes, including one defined as WorkspaceEventSink.

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CImportChannels :
  ...
  public WorkspaceEventSink,
  ...
{
   ...
}
```

This was previously defined as

```
typedef IDispEventSimpleImpl< 42, CImportChannels, &DIID_ICs3WorkspaceEvents>        WorkspaceEventSink ;
```

I have changed the definition to

```
typedef IDispEventImpl< 42, CImportChannels, &DIID_ICs3WorkspaceEvents, &LIBID_McAnalEventsNET, 1, 0 >        WorkspaceEventSink ;
```

Apart from changing IDispEventSimpleImpl to IDispEventImpl I have added the GUID of the type library and it major and minor version numbers.

Initially, I tried leaving the away the Major and Minor version numbers, but this resulted in a type-library-not-registered exception.

No other changes - for example to the sink map - were necessary.